# rails form_tag does not submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I have the following form for posting data using Ajax.

```
<%= form_tag(check_answer_path, :id =>'myForm', :method => 'post', :remote => true) do %>
   some form fields here...
<%= submit_tag('Next', :class => 'btn btn-primary') %></td>
```

But the form does not submit when I click on the Next button. To my surprise when I remove the :id and :remote attributes the form submits with no problem(but the page reloads which i do not want).

GOAL: I want to submit the form using `ajaxForm()` to handle the call back i.e `$("#myForm").ajaxForm()`. So I need the `:remote` attribute and I also need to identify my form(using the `:id` attribute).

Why is my form not submitting when I include `:id` and `:remote` attributes?

Am using rails 3.2.8 and jquery-rails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding remote to the form tag means that it's going to send the request using JS.

So it's actually submitting the form but it's not submitting it in the expected way.
In your controller add the following:

> ```
>  respond_to do |format|
>    format.js
>    format.html
>  end
> ```

and you will be able to respond to that request place a file.js.erb in your views and place the needed js code to complete the request.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like this answer. Let's see if it resolves the guy's problem.

Comment: @AlSayed Gamal yes I think this is what i need but am stock here. If the user clicks next, i want to submit the form via ajax and the respond will be an html form i.e I want to display the form again. Its a web-exam app am developing, so the if the user clicks next, I submit the form(via ajax) and display the form again with the next question. So i placed this <%= redirect_to exam_question_path(@exam, @next_question)%> in my show.js.erb to redirect to the next question. but its not working

Comment: redirect_to won't work in the view, it works only in controller.
you can redirect using javascript:
location.href= <your_path_here>